# Creating two read custom actuator endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Is there a way to create more than one GET custom actuator endpoint?

looking to have URLs like:

actuator/features/active

actuator/features/status

```
@Component
@Endpoint(id = "features")
public class FeaturesEndpoint {

    @ReadOperation
    public boolean isActive() {
        return true;
    }

/* Second read endpoint that is needed:
  @ReadOperation
    public boolean getStatus() {
        return true;
    }
*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/actuator/features")
public class FeaturesEndpoint {

  @GetMapping("/active")
  public boolean isActive() {
    return true;
  }


  @GetMapping("/status")
  public boolean getStatus() {
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: This is not an actuator endpoint